# British Spelling/Vocabulary in Mac?

Tags: macos, language, spell-check

Is there any way to have the British spelling/vocabulary on all the applications and spell-checkers in Mac?

Comment: Near identical question (exact but different variant of English): http://superuser.com/questions/153725/canadian-english-on-apple-products

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't done it before on my machine but you can change all the language settings via:

```
System Preferences > Language & Text
```

For the language itself you may need to add British English to the list via the `Edit List ...` button (10.6) but otherwise I believe it should be a visible option in the other tabs (i.e. Text, Format and Input Sources).

Comment: I can't find British English-US English is in the list though. :O?

Comment: Never mind-Fixed it from the instructions here: http://superuser.com/questions/153725/canadian-english-on-apple-products

Thanks anyways though! :)